# Вытащить переменную из if за его пределы

Tags: c#, .net, framework, clr

[image: Скрин ошибки:]Имеется простенькая конструкция:

```
if (x==5)
{
   y=6
}
Console.WriteLine(y) // ошибка
```

Мне очень важно вытащить значение “y” конкретно из-под if, вне ее я могу только объявить, но значение нужно под if

Как это можно сделать? Уже все перепробовал(

Comment: Инициализировать ее не забыли `int y = 0;`?

Comment: перед `if` написать `int y = default(int);`

Comment: какая ошибка ??

Comment: если `if` - это абстракция функции, то есть конструкция `out`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, получилось! помогло int y = default(int), Спасибо)

Comment: @ДмитрийТитов пожалуйста, впредь просто прочитайте внимательно ошибку (если не поможет поищите причину возникновения ошибки в интернете, по ее названию). Там же все ясно написано :) Удачи в изучение нового материала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вижу, что у вас уже все получилось, но я добавлю объяснение происходящему.

Дело в том, что если случится так, что `y` не будет равно 5, то выводить в консоль будет нечего, так как `y` на тот момент будет "ничем". Технически внутри этой переменной может оказаться что угодно, что лежало в том участке оперативной памяти, которое ей выделено при объявлении. То есть можно получить непредсказуемый результат. И чтобы защитить вас от подобного рода примитивных непредсказуемостей, компилятор запрещает вам использовать переменную с неприсвоенным значением на основе анализа вашего кода.

Есть несколько способов устранить эту неприятность:

1. присвоить ей что-нибудь при объявлении

   ```
   int y = 0;
   int x = 5;
   if (x==5)
   {
      y = 6;
   }
   Console.WriteLine(y);
   ```
2. использовать переменную внутри условного оператора

   ```
   int y;
   int x = 5;
   if (x==5)
   {
      y = 6;
      Console.WriteLine(y);
   }
   ```
3. Сделать ветвление условного оператора так, чтобы значение присваивалось в любом случае

   ```
   int y;
   int x = 5;
   if (x==5)
   {
      y = 6;
   }
   else
   {
      y = 0;
   }
   Console.WriteLine(y);
   ```
4. Способ для тех, кто знаком с исключениями: бросить исключение

   ```
   int y;
   int x = 5;
   if (x==5)
   {
      y = 6;
   }
   else
   {
      throw new Exception("x не равно 5!");
   }
   Console.WriteLine(y);
   ```